# ReferenceError: ajaxCall is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm a little bit lost... I have a site, which has a lot AJAX calls. I tried with some JavaScript textfield formatting, but that was too difficult to handle, so I decided to go back to normal without it. But right now none of my Ajax calls are working and I don't know why... All I got is this error:

```
ReferenceError: name-of-the-call is not defined
```

The calls are locating in the "scripts.js" file and this is included in the header from the very begining.

This is my header right now with an uploadify script and an arrow key navigation between the input fields.

```
<head>
<title>The title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/uploadify.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ajaxsubmit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php $timestamp = time();?>
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                },
                'height'   : 25,
                'buttonText' : 'bla bla...',
                'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                    document.getElementById("uploadedId").innerHTML+='<p style="margin: 0px;"><img width="25px" src="/img/success.png" /><b>' + data + '</b></p>';
                    var str = document.getElementById("uploadedFiles").value;
                    if(str == ""){
                        document.getElementById("uploadedFiles").value=data;
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("uploadedFiles").value+=',' + data;
                    }
                },
                'swf'      : '/scripts/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : '/scripts/uploadify.php'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(e){
                if(e.which==39)
                    $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();
                else if(e.which==37)
                    $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').focus();
                else if(e.which==40)
                    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').focus();
                else if(e.which==38)
                    $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').focus();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

This is the JS code (one of them, because none of them is fowrking...) what doesn't want to work (this is in the scripts.js):

```
function companyVatnr(str){

if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("companysearch").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("companysearch").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if(str.length>7){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("companysearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("companysearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxcompany.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

Can someone help me out, what could be the problem here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It think it must be some syntax error, but I can't find it...

Comment: So you use jquery and don't use jquery's ajax functions..... That's strange

Comment: I use jQuery for the uploadify file upload script, but for the ajax call don't. This was working fine until now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a syntax error in the scripts.js and that causes that ALL of my functions wasn't working. After fixing it, everything went back to normal.